# Chrome: Uncaught Syntax Error : Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototypejs

Page [here](http://joe-riggs.com/test/prot.html)

Seems like chrome is the only browser having problems with this bit of javascript.  I have found that if I remove the '//' from the CDATA tags chrome will give me a line number for the error - line 48. I dont even know where start with this bug unfortunately. The code works as expected but it just takes a bit longer to load/parse with chrome.

I have tried to use script as an external file (float.js) but the error is the same. In production the code will need to be included in the html body though. Any suggestions?

Edit: It was an extension causing this error, is there any way to code against this?

Comment: No error here (Chrome 13.0.782.218 m). Plz include the error text or something in your question? May be some add on?

Comment: Ah, thanks - it was the 'Smooth Gestures' extension.  I guess that means the code is OK - any way for me to defensively code against this for other users?

Comment: I don't think there any way to defensively code against this. Your scripting works. It's something else causing an error, but it doesn't interfere with your code. Ditch the extension, I'd say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the 'Smooth Gestures' extension. removing fixed